# Need to include org.json packages in MVC portlet to parse JSON in Liferay 7

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

Iam having a MVC portlet created using gradle, I want to parse JSON in it, so I included following packages like below,

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
```

Also I have included org.json in build.gradle file as you can see below:

```
dependencies {
compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "3.0.0"
compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.util.taglib", version: "2.0.0"
compileOnly group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api", version: "3.0.0"
compileOnly group: "javax.servlet", name: "javax.servlet-api", version: "3.0.1"
compileOnly group: "jstl", name: "jstl", version: "1.2"
compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "osgi.cmpn", version: "6.0.0"
//compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp', name: 'okhttp', version: '2.6.0'
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
compile group: 'org.apache.clerezza.ext', name: 'org.json.simple', version: '0.4'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5'
}
```

Compiling was successful but while deploying it in Liferay(7), Iam getting the below error:

While deploying in Liferay am getting this error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: mvc [952]_  Unreso
lved requirement: Import-Package: org.json; version="[20180813.0.0,20180814.0.0)
```

Should I include the package org.json inside liferay as well? If yes where should I add it?

I couldn't add any new packages Please anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare build-time dependencies to libraries that are not made available in Liferay out of the box (be it for the library itself, or for the specific version), the compiler will be happy, and bnd will generate (if required) runtime dependencies into your module's Manifest.mf.

If indeed these dependencies result in runtime dependencies, you'll have to make the libraries available to the OSGi runtime (Liferay in this case) as well. You do that in the same way you're deploying your own modules: Just drop them into Liferay's `deploy` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So you are saying I should download the bundle from this maven link:https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813 and place it in Liferay deploy folder right?

Comment: indeed. That should satisfy the runtime dependency. Unless you are missing more or transitive dependencies in addition.

Comment: or, you could embed inside you own module - just as an alternative

Comment: I would only consider embedding a dependency if it's *not* an OSGi bundle and I couldn't find a bundle version anywhere.